# Android Studio - Android SDK Tools 25.2.4 update failed

Tags: android, android-studio, updates

I recently downloaded Android studio, and while I tried to update Android SDK Tools, I encountered this problem.

[image: ???]

Since I'm new to Android Studio, I can't understand what's going wrong here. I really need the SDK tools update in order for me to develop for Android in LibGDX.

Comment: check the `logcat` and follow the instruction.

Comment: Retry and make sure all programs accessing the SDK are closed.

Comment: Link from deleted answer... http://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

Just update it without ui:

> tools/android update sdk --no-ui